# How does x_FormClosing work?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am developing Windows Form application and I wanted to execute some code when the user closes the window. Most people did it by using

[image]

This didn't work, and I've seen that you have to add events like this

[image]

Then, it actually worked, the code executes when I close the window but the next problem was there. The application didn't exit at closing the window. So I tried to add "Application.Exit();"

[image]

Now, it seemed to work. But it prints out the debugging message "Closed" two times. So it seems like even if the form is closed, Application.Exit() triggers the x_FormClosing method a second time ... any ideas?

Comment: *"you have to add events like this"* - you have to subscribe to event, using code or winforms designer. As for you question, `Application.Exit()` inside `FormClosing` will cause this event fired again.

Comment: Ok, that explains it at least. But is there a workaround?

Comment: `Closing` is called because form is closing, typically you have chance to discard closing (e.g. show confirmation at that moment). If it's the main form - application will finish (assuming what you didn't change `Application.Run(new Form1())` part). Unless ... (and here is a missing part, you didn't provide details regarding why application is not exiting).

Comment: Ok, thank you. That is too bad. So I guess the main form would be the form which opens when program starts? But yeah, the form I have these issues with isn't that one ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Form` hasn't fully closed yet and `Application.Exit` is going to call `.Close` on all open forms. `Closing` allows for the operation to be cancelled.

An application, by default will exit after all forms are closed. If you want this form to be a "master", consider putting it in the `Closed` event.

Comment: What do you mean with "putting it in the Closed event"?

Comment: @L.Mehmeti move the `Application.Exit` call.